# How do I pair values from two differently long columns in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames in format similar to this:

```
     name1
1    Retta Mclennon
2      Deloras Wurm
3    Tristan Partee
4   Lashonda Swayne
5 Christiane Bendel
```

and

```
    name2
1  Christiane Bendel
2     Tristan Partee
3       Ronni Sugrue
4    Lashonda Swayne
5       Alvaro Fahey
6   Tamie Kalinowski
7   Jefferson Levitt
8     Retta Mclennon
9        Haywood Neu
10      Deloras Wurm
```

I would like to create a new column in name1 in which value "Yes" would be ascribed to those rows which are contained in name2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a fairly easy task to do in r. It would be interesting to see why what you tried did not work

Comment: Read about `%in%` and `ifelse`.

Answer (score 1):

```
            > df1
                           Name
            1    Retta Mclennon
            2      Deloras Wurm
            3    Tristan Partee
            4   Lashonda Swayne
            5 Christiane Bendel


         > df2
                            Name
            1  Christiane Bendel
            2     Tristan Partee
            3       Ronni Sugrue
            4    Lashonda Swayne
            5       Alvaro Fahey
            6   Tamie Kalinowski
            7   Jefferson Levitt
            8     Retta Mclennon
            9        Haywood Neu
            10      Deloras Wurm


    colnames(df1)[2] <- "Match"
    df1$Match <- data.frame(ifelse(df1$Name %in% df2$Name , "Yes", "No"))

> df1
               Name                                     Match
1    Retta Mclennon                                      Yes
2      Deloras Wurm                                      Yes
3    Tristan Partee                                      Yes
4   Lashonda Swayne                                      Yes
5 Christiane Bendel                                      Yes
```